# Choosing the right project type and Windows Azure Services for SignalR ASP.NET project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, signalr, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I am developing my ASP.NET 4.5 C# + SingnalR web application that will be hosted on Windows Azure.

I am just starting out and totally new to Windows Azure. I signed up for the 30-day free trial. I am developing my app in Visual Studio 2012.

My question is regarding the available services that I need to choose in order to develop and publish my specific application on Windows Azure. Which infrastructure I need to use if I intend to build a real-time application using SignalR with Windows Azure Service Bus?

I know that I will need to **scale the app + signalr machine behind a load balancer**. I also know that I will need to **connect SignalR with the Windows Azure Service Bus**.

**What type of project should I create in Visual Studio** and **what type of service I should choose from Windows Azure**. I know that there are 'Web sites', 'Virtual Machines' and 'Cloud services' -- but I don't know which one is applicable for my specific application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the project type:

**Web Sites** is basically a stripped-down cloud service that takes a lot of work off your shoulders – basically you have less options as a developer, but profit from a simpler programming model. You can't do everything you can do with a cloud service, but if your app doesn't need anything that Web Sites can't provide, you'll likely be better off choosing this.

**Cloud Service** is the classic / default project type. You have all the power of the Azure APIs at your hands, but other than with Web Sites, also have to work at a lower level. **I would recommend this type,** unless your app is "simple" enough to make do with Web Sites – wether or not that is the case, only you can answer by taking a closer look at the features and limits of each project type.

**Virtual machine** is just that: a Virtual Machine drive in the cloud. You can choose an Operating System other than what Cloud Services use - e.g. Windows XP or some Linux dist. - and then install whatever service you need, e.g. Apache. In my opinion, you should only choose this if you need a specific OS or service. The downside of VMs is that you are responsible for updating and mainting them – whereas Cloud Services are automatically updated (Windows Updates etc.) for you.

---

**Edit:** some more information regarding the Cloud Service project type, in case you decide to go for that:

Cloud Services support 2 kinds of roles: Worker roles and Web roles. You scale your app by increasing the number of a certain role – e.g., you could create a Role that hosts your SignalR service and then increase the number of *role instances* if you monitor increasing load. The *Azure Load Balancer* automatically distributes all incoming requests to a *public endpoint* you define per-role, so you don't have to load-balance yourself (you'll have to use stateless sessions though).

From a programming perspective, a Worker Role is basically a class with an OnStart, OnStop and a Run method that needs to run until the role instance is stopped. What the role does is entirely up to you – e.g. you could start a SignalR service in the OnStart method and check for requests in the Run method.

A Web Role is just like a Worker Role but comes with ASP.Net. The OnStart, OnStop and Run methods are still there, but you need not use them and can instead use ASP.Net events (like application start).

If you want to use ASP.Net for your app, you should choose a Web Role. You can still put all your business logic in a Worker Role and let your Web Role delegate requests to it e.g. via *Azure Queues* – that way you can scale both roles independently.

You may also be interested in **[OWIN](http://owin.org/)** or more specifically the **[Katana project](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/documentation)**. In a nutshell, Owin is an abstraction layer that makes your web project technology independent - you can e.g. use IIS / ASP.Net and then switch to a self-hosted solution if you desire. Katana supports SignalR, so you could also host SignalR directly in a Worker Role and skip ASP.Net entirely (by implementing a JavaScript client yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SignalR Scaleout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus) - most likely, you want to develop your web application and deploy the web application to an Azure Cloud Service.  The Cloud Service runs any number of instances behind a load balancer without any configuration on your part other than pointing your CNAME record to the Cloud Service.  For the SignalR part, to make it scalable, you will want to use the Azure Service Bus Relay as a backplane for your SignalR implementation (again, load balanced without you having to woory lots about configuring/maintaining).  The referenced example is a good start.

Comment: Thansk for yout answer. I've read this article and watch some Microsoft videos about SingnalR, but their developers don't recommend going with a backplane solution and they suggested something like a P2P connection, sending messages between connected machines. I haven't found any information regarding benchmarks done with SignalR and Azure Backplane so how can I be sure that it can scale well?